# Is there any plugin system for supabase?

Tags: javascript, plugins, supabase

Is there any plugin system for supabase like unity assetstore? I need to search for the plugins but not like postgres extensions in supabase. If there is, where can i find them? (supabase plugins for my react project) It will be good if anyone share any source with me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.